# Optimize code: Iterate through Subclasses of UIViewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, loops

I'm fairly new to swift, so I have a basic question about the code I'm trying to create.

I have a `UIScrollView` and I want to add multiple `UIViewController`.

This is the code I was working with in the first place:

```
let obj1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Page1VC") as! Page1VC
        let obj2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Page2VC") as! Page2VC
        let obj3 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Page3VC") as! Page3VC
        let obj4 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Page4VC") as! Page4VC
        let obj5 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Page5VC") as! Page5VC

        self.containerScrollView.addSubview(obj2.view)
        obj2.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
        self.addChildViewController(obj2)

        self.containerScrollView.addSubview(obj1.view)
        obj1.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
        self.addChildViewController(obj1)

        self.containerScrollView.addSubview(obj3.view)
        obj3.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
        self.addChildViewController(obj3)

        self.containerScrollView.addSubview(obj4.view)
        obj4.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
        self.addChildViewController(obj4)

        self.containerScrollView.addSubview(obj5.view)
        obj5.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
        self.addChildViewController(obj5)

        obj1.view.frame.origin =  CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0)
        obj2.view.frame.origin =  CGPoint.init(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 0)
        obj3.view.frame.origin = CGPoint.init(x: 2*UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 0)
        obj4.view.frame.origin = CGPoint.init(x: 3*UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 0)
        obj5.view.frame.origin = CGPoint.init(x: 4*UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 0)
```

I hope we can all agree on, that this code is not very good and/or flexible. I wanted to achieve an arbitrary amount of pages for my `UIScrollView`, so I concluded that I needed a Loop for that purpose.

I ended up with this code:

```
repeat {
            let vc = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Page\(x+1)VC"))!
            obj.append(vc)
            self.containerScrollView.addSubview(obj[x].view)
            obj[x].willMove(toParentViewController: self)
            self.addChildViewController(obj[x])
            obj[x].view.frame.origin =  CGPoint(x: (CGFloat(x))*UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 0)
            x += 1
            print("Page \(x) sucessfully initialized")
        } while (x < segmentControl.numberOfSegments)
```

That code is working perfectly fine, but I want to change some of the data in the `childViewController`. Which leads me to these changes:

```
repeat {
            let vc = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Page\(x+1)VC"))! as! Page**\(x+1)**VC
            **vc.setup = setup**
            obj.append(vc)
            self.containerScrollView.addSubview(obj[x].view)
            obj[x].willMove(toParentViewController: self)
            self.addChildViewController(obj[x])
            obj[x].view.frame.origin =  CGPoint(x: (CGFloat(x))*UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 0)
            x += 1
            print("Page \(x) sucessfully initialized")
        } while (x < segmentControl.numberOfSegments)
```

I marked the changes in Bold. 
That code is obviously not working, since it is not possible to declare the type of the `UIViewController` as `as! Page**\(x+1)**VC`

All that leads to my Question: Can I iterate through different subclasses like described in the long version of the code by using loops? Or do I have to resort to the long version of my code?

Comment: If you always do the "kind of same thing" in `setup()`, you may use a Protocol, that each of your VC will comply. Else, you can create all of yours VC elements, set them up, then put them in an array and loop for that array.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That was also an idea I had, but it will leave me with not being able to create an arbitrary amount of `UIViewController`. I could in general have a function, pass in a number and then according to the number it will create x amount of `UIViewController`, but I would need to write non loopable code first. I will try it, thank you!